# Django actual value in choice field form

Tags: django, django-forms, foreign-keys

I have models like this:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I also made a form in which I want to change current Project assigned Profile:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'project'
        ]
```

My view looks like this:

```
def change_project(request, user):
    user = User.objects.filter(username=user)[:1].get()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'datafiller/change_project.html', context)
```

I can change the project using this form, but every time I want to do it again the form [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjHFQ.png)

How can I show in the form the current project instead of "------"?

Comment: You should probably rename ProjectForm to ProfileForm or AssignProjectForm for clarity. It's confusing to see a model Profile on a Project form.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's my very first project and I'm constantly changing things trying to figure out how they work. When I'm sure that everything is ok I rename things to make them clear. Maybe it's not the best way, but like I said I'm still learning. Thank's a lot for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not ground the `ProjectForm` in case you render the form with a GET requuest:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def change_project(request, user):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'datafiller/change_project.html', {'form': form})
```